# How to generate a random number between (1-100) from MD5 hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, md5, sha256

Simply, I want to generate a random number between 1-100 from an MD5 hash.

**I will always use a email string as the argument.**

The reason is I want to create a simple a/b test to determine a specific email layout depending on the number returned.

This is my solution but I do not know if it is accurate, and frankly I'm not entirely sure if I know what I am doing..

```
parseInt(crypto.createHash('md5').update('example@gmail.com').digest("hex"), 16) % 10**2

52 is returned
```

Could anyone lead me in the right direction and give a detailed explanation on what is happening? Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: You want the same MD5 hash to always produce the same "random" number?

Comment: How do you define "accurate?"

Comment: @kindall Yes for that particular email, but each email will have it's own random number which won't change, just like my example above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the above comment will answer your question.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the MD5 hash for this?  The random number will have a lot of collisions (different emails that have the same random number).

Comment: Because I want a simple way to determine which email layout to use. My thoughts was this is easy to generate depending on the integer returned. However the MD5 produces a complex string and there is no way how I can determine what email layout to show from this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see what you mean, but I don't know the best solution.

Comment: It's not clear to me how an MD5 hash is going to help you pick an email layout.

Comment: Basically, I just want to generate a random number from the email..so I can create an a/b test.

Comment: The bytes of the MD5 are independent, so you can just take the first byte, which is 0-255, and use that to make your decision. Unless you literally need it to be 1-100 for some reason, but you probably don't.

Comment: I think you should change the title.  It doesn't seem like you really want a 'random' number, but you want to assign deterministic values to an email address in a pseudo-random way by using the hash, right?  You're using a hash to 'scramble' the email address so you don't cluster similar email addresses with the same setting, right?

Comment: Taking the 128-bit MD5 result mod 100 produces a very slight bias. Since this is not for cryptographic purposes, it is safe to ignore this bias. However, taking only the last byte of byte of MD5 mod 100 introduces a significant bias and should be avoided. Perhaps the best choice is to take any 52 bits as an integer and then divide by 2\*\*52 to produce a floating point number, then multiply by 100 and floor the result.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the library [seedrandom](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) you can seed the number generator.
Seeding a number generator ensures that numbers will always generate in same order when starting from "scratch".
It's great in auto generated mazes and game levels(Think level seeds in minecraft)

Using this library you could then do something like the below to get your consistent results.

```js
var myrng = new Math.seedrandom('example@example.com');
console.log("int 1: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 2: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 3: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 4: " + myrng.int32());
console.log('round 2, repeating the above with same seed');
myrng = new Math.seedrandom('example@example.com');
console.log("int 1: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 2: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 3: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 4: " + myrng.int32());
console.log('round 3, repeating the above with a different seed');
myrng = new Math.seedrandom('#example@example.com');
console.log("int 1: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 2: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 3: " + myrng.int32());
console.log("int 4: " + myrng.int32());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/3.0.5/seedrandom.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer, I was looking to distribute strings into a few "buckets" with more or less even distribution and `seedrandom` seems like a perfect tool for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your first part is creating the MD5 hash:

```js
crypto.createHash('md5').update('example@gmail.com').digest("hex")
// e820bb4aba5ad74c5a6ff1aca16641f6
```

The md5 hash produced is a 32 digit hexadecimal number.  `parseInt(hash, 16)` parses that as an integer.  That's too big for an integer though so you get a large floating point number.  I'm not sure what exactly is going on in that conversion.  Then you take the modulo 100 which gives a value from 0 to 99.

It would be a little easier to reason if you take the first two digits of the md5 and get a number from 0-255 and base your settings off that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, why between 0-255? Can you give an example and I will mark your answer as correct, as it's the closest to what I want.

Comment: because you're taking the first byte of the hash. the byte has a value of 00 to FF in hexadecimal, which is 0 to 255 in decimal

Answer (score 1):

`Number`s in Javascript are just 64bit floats and hence are only good for about 15 decimal digits.  Taking the modulus of values with ~37 decimal digits will mean the low order bits are all effectively zero and you'll get relatively sparse output.  e.g.:

```
a = Array(100).fill(0)
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  d = Math.random() * 2**128
  a[d % 100] += 1
}
```

note that the `Math.random() * 2**128` is roughly equivalent to generating the hash of a random email.  this gives me an `a` like:

```
[
  409, 0, 0, 0, 408, 0, 0, 0, 408, 0, 0, 0,
  398, 0, 0, 0, 420, 0, 0, 0, 434, 0, 0, 0,
  356, 0, 0, 0, 401, 0, 0, 0, 398, 0, 0, 0,
  423, 0, 0, 0, 346, 0, 0, 0, 397, 0, 0, 0,
  406, 0, 0, 0, 378, 0, 0, 0, 429, 0, 0, 0,
  410, 0, 0, 0, 421, 0, 0, 0, 358, 0, 0, 0,
  389, 0, 0, 0, 363, 0, 0, 0, 398, 0, 0, 0,
  398, 0, 0, 0, 426, 0, 0, 0, 396, 0, 0, 0,
  430, 0, 0, 0
]
```

indicating that only values divisible by 4 are possible, and hence 75 of your 100 values will never be used.

As James K. Polk commented, taking the modulus is also slightly biased, but the above is a much bigger issue.  I'd also second the suggestion using division as this keeps the high order bits and maintains the entropy, something like:

```
digest = crypto.createHash('md5').update('example@gmail.com').digest("hex")
Math.floor(parseInt(digest, 16) / 2**128 * 100)
```

you can use something similar to above loop to see that this gives a uniform distribution of outputs

note that both of the above generate values from 0 to 99, so you probably want to add 1 to the result

another way is to go with Node's `BigInt` type, something like:

```
digest = crypto.createHash('md5').update('example@gmail.com').digest()
Number(digest.readBigUInt64BE() / (2n**64n / 100n + 1n))
```

which avoids converting to strings and back again, but gets to basically the same answer.